# Generating CSV output using XSLT

Tags: csv, xslt

I have several information entries that I want to separate with a comma. However, each entry could be empty, and if the first-appearing entry is empty, then comma should not appear. For example:

if we have four XSLT parameters: name, phone number, address, occupation

and we have

- Name: John
- Phone number: 111-111-1111
- Address: Imaginary street
- Occupation: Baker

Then final string should be:

*John, 111-111-1111, Imaginary street, Baker*

if the name and phone number parameters were empty or null, then final string should be:

*Imaginary street, Baker*

if only phone number null or empty, then final string should be:

*John, Imaginary street, Baker*

In a language like C#, I would write the code like this:

```
foreach (EntryObject entry in entryList)
{
    if (firstEntry == true && entry.Type != EntryType.Age && entry.Type != EntryType.Sex)
    {
        finalString += entry.ValueString;
        firstEntry = false;
    }
    else if (firstEntry == false && entry.Type != EntryType.Age && entry.Type != EntryType.Sex)
    { 
        finalString += ", " + entry.ValueString;
    }
}
return finalString;
```

However, I heard that variables in XSLT are immutable. How should I approach this problem in XSLT?

Edit:
The xml entry would look something like this:

```
<AddressBook>
    <PersonalInfo>
        <Age>33</Age>
        <Sex>Male</Sex>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
        <Address>Imaginary Street</Address>
        <Occupation>Baker</Occupation>
    </PersonalInfo>
</AddressBook>
```

Note that certain entries could be empty, and I will only use name, phonenumber, address and occupation. Age and Sex should be ignored.

Comment: What does your XML input look like?

Comment: Is this XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @MatthewGreen I edited my original post to include an example.

Comment: @MichaelKay I am using XSLT 1.1. (I'm new to XSLT, but I am assuming this from the entry <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" ...>

Comment: @J.L, See a very generic, simple and short solution.

Comment: @J.L, there's no such thing as XSLT 1.1; it refers to a working draft that was abandoned in 2001. Unfortunately one edition of my book made extensive reference to it and was published just about when it was abandoned, so readers of the book have a habit of using "1.1" not realizing. So the stylesheet might be a 1.0 stylesheet or a 2.0 stylesheet. The two versions are VERY different.

Comment: @MichaelKay I'm not sure where else I can check to find the version number. I apologize if this sounds very elementary, I'm fairly new to XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an XPath condition that matches only the non-empy elements (`string-length(.)>0` or simply `string(.)`), and then use the `position()` function to check if an element is the first or not. Input XML:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <name>John</name>
    <phoneNumber>111-111-1111</phoneNumber>
    <address>Imaginary street</address>
    <occupation>Baker</occupation>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Jane</name>
    <address>Another street</address>
    <occupation>Decorator</occupation>
  </item>
  <item>
    <address>Unknown</address>
  </item>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <textItem>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[string(.)]">
        <xsl:if test="position()>1">
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </textItem>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where the first template is the one actually doing the work, `<xsl:template match="text()">` removes the text contained in unmatched elements (by default XSLT processor would copy such text to the output) and `<xsl:template match="root">` generates the root element of the output document.

Result:

```
<root>
  <textItem>John,111-111-1111,Imaginary street,Baker</textItem>
  <textItem>Jane,Another street,Decorator</textItem>
  <textItem>Unknown</textItem>
</root>
```

If you are interested in only some of the fields you just select them using the union operator (`|`) - e.g. if you want only phone, address and occupation in the example above modify the XSLT to be:

```
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <textItem>
      <xsl:for-each select="(phoneNumber|address|occupation)[string(.)]">
        <xsl:if test="position()>1">
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </textItem>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after inspecting the xml given to me, I realized that there are other elements that I don't use under that element - for example under <item> there would be age, sex, name, phone number, address and occupation and I will only use name, phone number, address and occupation - so this strategy of checking position()>1 wouldn't work. Unfortunately I have no control over the given xml.

Comment: what are  <xsl:template match="text()"> and <xsl:template match="root"> for?

Comment: Also, can I use this code under a fo:block? ex) <fo:block ...> <xsl:template match="item">...... </xsl:template> </fo:block ...>

Comment: See additional explanations in the answer concerning `<xsl:template match="text()">` and `<xsl:template match="root">`. I don't understand the question about `<fo:block>` - I suggest you create a new question for that.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a generic solution that accepts the list of "black-listed" element names as a parameter:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pIgnoreThese" select="' Age Sex '"/>

 <xsl:template match="PersonalInfo">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "*[normalize-space()
    and
      not(contains($pIgnoreThese, concat(' ', name(), ' ')))
     ]"/>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="PersonalInfo/*">
  <xsl:if test="position() >1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<AddressBook>
        <PersonalInfo>
            <Age>33</Age>
            <Sex>Male</Sex>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <PhoneNumber>111-111-1111</PhoneNumber>
            <Address>Imaginary Street</Address>
            <Occupation>Baker</Occupation>
        </PersonalInfo>
        <PersonalInfo>
            <Age>33</Age>
            <Sex>Male</Sex>
            <Name></Name>
            <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
            <Address>Imaginary Street</Address>
            <Occupation>Baker</Occupation>
        </PersonalInfo>
        <PersonalInfo>
            <Age>33</Age>
            <Sex>Male</Sex>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
            <Address>Imaginary Street</Address>
            <Occupation>Baker</Occupation>
        </PersonalInfo>
</AddressBook>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
John, 111-111-1111, Imaginary Street, Baker
Imaginary Street, Baker
John, Imaginary Street, Baker
```